# Limiting Default Checked checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox, each

I have problem regarding on how i will limit my default checked checkbox.
for example i have 7 checkboxes. and i want to limit it with 3 default checked checkboxes once the page is load.

```
this should be the output:

Checkbox1 : true
Checkbox2 : true
Checkbox3 : true
Checkbox4 : false
Checkbox5 : false
Checkbox6 : false
Checkbox7 : false
```

Here's my sample code:

```
var mvp = 3;
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input:checkbox").each(function( index ) {
    ($this).attr("checked",true);
});

});
```

I'm stock with this, i don't know where i will put my counter (mvp) inside my each function. in this code, all my checkboxes are checked :D.

Sorry for a newbie question, please help me..

Comment: `($this)` or `$(this)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actual no need for a counter since the `each` function will pass in the index.  Just use the index as the counter.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:checkbox").each(function( index ) {
           this.checked = (index < 3);
    });
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/SB6aD/2/

Comment: Logically acceptable.. i modified this code. and it works :D thanks @Kevin

Comment: but actually, this will fail if you have one `<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />`

Comment: @user2593560 See my update there is actually no need for a counter when using `each` since it passes the index.

Comment: @KevinBowersox ahh I see... so, what I mean was if the OP wanted the last one coded in HTML as checked.. haha well then, that's not what the OP wanted... :) so your answer is correct... :)

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery `:lt` selector,it will match all element which has a smaller index.

Example:

```
$(function() {
  var mvp = 3;
  $('input:checkbox:lt('+mvp+')').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Based of @Kevin Bowersox's code:

```
var mvp = 3;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var counter = 0;
    $("input:checkbox").each(function( index ) {
        if(counter < mvp){
           $(this).attr("checked",true);
           counter++;
        }
    });
});
```

i modified this code into this:

```
var mvp = 3;
    $(document).ready(function() {
$("input:checkbox").each(function( index ) {
        if(index < mvp){
           $(this).attr("checked",true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: We had the same idea to use `index`

Answer (score 0):

Don't setup the default state of your page with Javascript, use the HTML "checked" attribute.

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In this example the car checkbox will be checked.

Answer (score 0):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B8z9F/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");
    checkboxes.each(function( index ) {
        if (checkboxes.filter(':checked').length >= 3) {return;}
        this.checked = true;

    });

});
```

Comment: This loop is bad. You're going to run a query for each step in the loop. Just collect the correct elements and iterate over them with a counter.

Answer (score 0):

Decrement `mvp` after you check each checkbox. When it reaches 0, start unchecking.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mvp = 3;
    $("input:checkbox").each(function( index ) {
        ($this).attr("checked", mvp > 0);
        mvp--;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check ***[.slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)***

```
$(function() {
  var mvp = 3;
  $('input:checkbox').slice(0, mvp).prop('checked', true);
  $('input:checkbox').slice(mvp).prop('checked', false);
});
```

***[See the JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q26gT/)***

And note, `checked` is rather a property than an attribute, use `.prop` instead of `.attr`.