# Limit/disable/enable checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

i have a problem regarding to this link :[Limiting default checked checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20962477/limiting-default-checked-checkboxes/20962592#20962592).

I extend the code for validation of the script, Here's what i want to do.

1. I want a default checked checkbox.
2. i want to limit the selection of checkbox for example: if mvp is 3 i should select 3 and disable the rest of the checkbox just like this. [Limit Checkbox](http://jsfiddle.net/jc_garcia0527/3GrEA/).
3. I want to disable submit button if the selection is not reach for example if the given maximum number is 5. the submit button will not be enable if the selection is not 5 checked.

Here's my sample code:

```
var mvp = 5;

$(document).ready(function() {


    $("input:checkbox").each(function( index ) {
        this.checked = ( index < mvp );
    });

$("input:checkbox").click(function() {

  var bol = $("input:checkbox:checked").length != mvp;

  if(bol){
  alert("You have to choose "+ mvp +" mvp's only");
  this.checked = false;
  $("#button-cart").attr("disabled", true);
  }
  else{
  $("input:checkbox").not(":checked").attr("disabled",bol);
  $("#button-cart").attr("disabled", false);
  }
});

});
```

Here's the fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jc_garcia0527/m5Ms5/)

Based on the example i set the value of mvp in 5. the when the page loads there are default 5 checkbox checked. then if you uncheck 1 then the alert will trigger that it says you should have 5 mvp's, then the button will disable. once you check again a checkbox, the button will appear. but there are 2 left checkboxes that the user can select. but if the user exceed to 5 selections then the alert will trigger again and return it to 5 checked checkboxes. problem here is the button will remain disabled.

Can you help me to do this kind of logic :D thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
var mvp = 5;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").each(function (index) {
        this.checked = (index < mvp);
    }).click(function () {
       en_dis= $("input:checkbox:checked").length < mvp
       $('#button-id').prop('disabled', en_dis);
       // to disable other checkboxes
       $('input:checkbox:checked').length >= mvp &&
           $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").prop('disabled',true);
    }).change(function () {
       if ($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= mvp) {
           this.checked = false;
       }
    });
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RcLDV/3/) and [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RcLDV/4/)

Comment: Thanks @Rohan Kumar This is what exactly i want to do. except that the checkboxes are not disabled when it exceeds

Comment: @user2593560 now check my answer and **updated demo**

Comment: Working demo is fine :D Updated Demo have error. because if the user check the 6th checkbox from loading which has default 5 checked checkbox, the 6th and 7th checkbox will disable. but if i will uncheck 1 of the 5 checkbox default. the 6th and 7th checkbox should open again for checking.

Comment: Yes, in my opinion you should work with `Working Demo`, in case if the user needs to `change` the `checkbox` after selecting `5 checkboxes`, then he can do it without any boundation.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't set the checked property of the checkbox and also disable the button.

Here you go:

```
$(function () {
    var $button = $('#button-id'),
        mvp     = 5;

    $("input:checkbox").each(function (index) {
        this.checked = (index < mvp);
    }).on("click", function () {
        if ($("input:checkbox:checked").length != mvp) {
            alert("You have to choose " + mvp + " mvp's only");
            $button.prop("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $("input:checkbox").not(":checked").prop("disabled", false);
            $button.prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R79cM/

Comment: upon loading of the page. there will be a default 5 checked checkbox right? but when i tried it to check for the 6th checkbox the alert will trigger and return it again the 5 checked checkboxes but the button still disabled.

Comment: The user should'nt choose not exceeding the given mvp. the program should restrict the user to check another boxes except for 5 checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
$("input:checkbox").each(function (index) {
    this.checked = (index < mvp);
});
$("#button-id").attr("disabled", true);
disable();
$("input:checkbox").change(function () {
    var bol = $("input:checkbox:checked").length != mvp;
    if (bol) {
        alert("You have to choose " + mvp + " mvp's only");            
        $("#button-id").attr("disabled", true);
        enable();
    } else {
        $("input:checkbox").not(":checked").attr("disabled", bol);
        $("#button-id").attr("disabled", false);
        disable();
    }        
});
function enable(){
    $("input:checkbox").not(":checked").each(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
    });
}
function disable(){
    $("input:checkbox").not(":checked").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
    });
}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/m5Ms5/1/)